# Where can I find code responsible for SQL query execution on engine level for HyperSQL?

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I found next git repo with [HyperSQL](https://github.com/OndraZizka/HSQLDB). And I'm checking [JDBC interfaces](https://github.com/OndraZizka/HSQLDB/tree/master/hsqldb/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc) for DB usage.

For example, I want to create connection with DB, and execute some statements:

```
Connection connection = ...
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String query = "CREATE TABLE mytable (id IDENTITY , value VARCHAR)";
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

As I can see, next sequence of internal JDBC driver classes invocations happens:

```
JDBCDriver -> JDBCConnection -> JDBCStatement -> Session -> Result (?) -> ? -> HSQLDB
```

For [JDBCStatement](https://github.com/OndraZizka/HSQLDB/blob/master/hsqldb/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCStatement.java#L152):

```
public synchronized ResultSet executeQuery(
            String sql) throws SQLException {

        fetchResult(sql, StatementTypes.RETURN_RESULT,
                    JDBCStatementBase.NO_GENERATED_KEYS, null, null);

        return getResultSet();
}
```

And for [fetchResult](https://github.com/OndraZizka/HSQLDB/blob/master/hsqldb/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCStatement.java#L2081)

```
private void fetchResult(String sql, int statementRetType,
                             int generatedKeys, int[] generatedIndexes,
                             String[] generatedNames) throws SQLException {
   ...
   resultIn = connection.sessionProxy.execute(resultOut);
   ...
}
```

Next - [Session](https://github.com/OndraZizka/HSQLDB/blob/master/hsqldb/src/org/hsqldb/Session.java#L966) invocation.

But where can I find code responsible for execution of SQL statements via DBMS engine?

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB source code is in a Subversion (not Git) repository hosted on SourceForge.net: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/svn/HEAD/tree/base/trunk/

If you follow from The Session.execute(Result ...) method, and find the case for EXECDIRECT, you will see the statement is first compiled, then executed. You can follow from there, which includes a large number of classes responsible for compiling and executing different types of SQL statement.

Comment: But why first it's executeDirectStatement, and then again performPostExecute for the same result?

Comment: performPostExecute covers any work that is need besides the actual query, that needs to be done. SQL execution is not simply creating a result, and has to deal with transactions, resources and other things.